# Mac Hardware Details - specifically iMac

Tags: mac

I am amazed to see an Apple iMac. How is it possible to have all hardware within the size of LCD Screen?

What kind of magic does Apple use?

DVD-ROM, Screen, Hard Disk, Processor, Motherboard ???

I want to know "how they are implemented physically?"

It means like a figure as follow.

[image]

Can someone explain about Apple's hardware? (like here is processor, & here is harddisk & so on).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll just assume you're talking about an iMac.  Maybe this is what you're looking for?

[iMac 20" Teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/First-Look/iMac-20-Inch/658/1)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Nice information in given link.

Answer (score 4):

This might answer it. [Disassembled iMac](http://www.kodawarisan.com/imac_2007_mid/imac_2007_mid_01.html)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Nice information in given link.

Answer (score 3):

They're using notebook parts, which are designed to fit in a smaller space than desktop parts. This allows them to put a lot in a small amount of space, but it comes at the price of expandability and cost.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X Leopard is an operating System and not a computer. If you want a look at the hardware used in a Mac made by Apple Inc. you can check out sites such as [Kodawarisan](http://mactree.sannet.ne.jp/~kodawarisan/imac_intel/imac_intel01.html)