# Understanding Mac Mini Hardware

Tags: mac, computer-building, mac-mini

From my previous questions

1. https://superuser.com/questions/32104/postmortem-of-an-iphone

Above link describes what is there an iPhone internally ?

2. [Mac Hardware Details - specifically iMac](https://superuser.com/questions/26604/mac-hardware-details-specifically-imac)

same way Above link describes what is there an iMac internally ?

similarly, I am amazed to see the mac mini size like a small box.

- How does it cover all the things like mother board, processor, harddisk within a single small box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iFixit has a [**teardown of a Mac Mini**](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Mac-mini-A1283/659/1).
[**Here**](http://blog.benguild.com/2005/01/mac-mini-complete-technical-disassembly-documentation-pdf/) you'll find a PDF with disassembly instructions of a Mac Mini.

The components are not far from the ones used for laptops: small size, huge integration.